# Unable to use the dimension table as a nested table in SQL server data tools

Tags: sql-server, database, data-warehouse, sql-data-tools

I have the following relationship set up between my fact table and dimension tables.

[image]

When trying to create a data mining structure,  I had to choose the dimension table Dimension_Status as a nested table for the fact table as I'm trying to predict the probability of "TimelyResponse" in the fact table using the "IssuedVia" in the Dimension_Status table. But when trying to do so, I get the following error.

```
Dimension_Status table cannot be used as a nested table because it does not have a many-to-one relationship with the case table.  You need to create a many-to-one relationship between the two tables in the data source file
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting this error though my dimension tables are maintaining a many to one relationship with the fact table? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely missing the mark here (I haven't done a great deal of data-mining using SSAS), but from what I can tell nested tables are the "Many" side of a many-to-many relationship. From the [MSDN article on Nested Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175659.aspx) it shows the "Products" table as being nested in the "Customer" table, because each Customer can have many Products:

[image]

> In this diagram, the first table, which is the parent table, contains
> information about customers, and associates a unique identifier for
> each customer. The second table, the child table, contains the
> purchases for each customer. The purchases in the child table are
> related to the parent table by the unique identifier, the CustomerKey
> column. The third table in the diagram shows the two tables combined.
>
> A nested table is represented in the case table as a special column
> that has a data type of TABLE. For any particular case row, this kind
> of column contains selected rows from the child table that pertain to
> the parent table.

So it looks like nested tables are not what you're after - unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the SSA data mining tools to recommend the appropriate approach (unless switching them around and making the `DimStatus` table your Case table and `Fact_CustomerComplaints` your Nested table will work in your situation.)

Comment: Yeah I tried switching the tables. When I do so, during the state at which we select input columns and predict columns I get stuck. If I take this approach its not showing the key column for fact column. Without selecting a key column I can't move forward as well :(

Comment: Does the column need to be nested? I didn't think you had to nest to get at dimension tables in general. ..

Comment: Basically what I have done is created the dimension and fact tables separately and created relationships between them using surrogate keys. Mapping wise this relationship is one-many. Now I need a column from dimension column as an input to my mining requirement. Therefore I had to select that table as a nested table in SQL data tools in order to get access to that column. Am I doing something wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, your arrows are backwards.

Reverse the relationships so the tables you want to be nested are pointing to your `Fact_` table.

Like so:

[image]